# how to test php scalability

Tags: php, performance, scalability

I am rumning centOS on a VPS with good performance.
I have a PHP file that calculates some combinations for a game for each user that plays this game. It calculates the logic of a game that is built with FLASH.

I want to test this file to see how the response time is doing with 1000 users simultaneously 
I have no idea where to start from or what to look for.

If anybody can give me some tips, let me know.

And I have another question. how do I know if my application is scalable ?

Comment: Using a tool like ApacheBench (ab) is always a good starting point

Comment: Why Flash in this day and age!!!?

Comment: @Ben Carey - because its alternative, HTML5, has 0 security and lets anybody to steal your source code.

Comment: @nevergone you can also decompile flash, you just add "not all devices suport flash" to the list of possible problems (think of the future of your game in terms of devices/portability) :-\ you can obfuscate and shrink the JS, this should stop just-for-fun reverse-engineers

Comment: @nicogawenda , if you decompile flash you do not obtain 100% readable code, as you do with HTML5 . Flash is evolving and is still available on 90% of all PC that use internet. The only bad thing is that is not supported on mobile devices. You can obtain much better RIA in FLASH than in HTML5 and faster. And not all browsers support HTML5.

Answer (score 4):

There are few tools out there you can use.

[ApacheBench](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ApacheBench)

[Httperf](http://code.google.com/p/httperf/)

[HP LoadRunner](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/software.html?compURI=1175451#.UO1d8IlevDM)

http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php

[xDebug](http://xdebug.org/) has a profiler built in. will allow you to see the all the function calls, average and cumulative call times and the total script execution time

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) for this.

To test end-user performance, do not run it at the server. The testing tool will use the same resources as the script, and localhost network communication is not a real-life scenario. There are also some cloud based stress-test services (like http://loadimpact.com or http://www.neustar.biz/enterprise/web-performance/load-testing-packages , but they are not free)

Also, take a look at memory/CPU consumption of the overall system, not only of the script itself. Usually, you should gain quite some improvements in resource usage using Nginx and FastCGI.

Scalability highly depends on what your script is doing, what resources it consumes and how. At the end it might be as easy as just adding another server and a loadbalancer.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to test this file to see how the response time is doing with 1000 users simultaneously I have no idea where to start from or what to look for.

Hire someone who has been there and done that.    I know, this may seem expensive on its face, but compared to trying to climb the vertical wall of process, tool, requirements, reporting, analysis it's going to be cheaper to hire someone.

Also telling is your use of the term simultaneous.  Human populations do not operate this way.    Simultaneous behavior is governed by a clock tick and an automated process.   Natural populations are chaotic but may arrive in a short window where each is operating autonomously from one another, but on the system generating distinct request load.

I audit a lot of developer generated performance tests.   The audits never go well in the areas of load model deisgn, implementation, pacing, data, etc...

Especially if money is on the line for a 1000 concurrent users, it's worth the money to hire the expert or a service for the short period of time required to conduct the test.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try https://loadimpact.com/, it provides good monitoring tools and customisable user test scenarios with Lua scripting language too, we used this site recently to test scalability in our live streaming application, it's fairly cheap to get a 1 month membership that allows unlimited tests with 3000 concurrent users, we tweaked the site and could withhold 12000+ concurrent users within an hour in a recent show and pretty confident with it now.

Comment: If you want to ask about how we knew breaking point of site with only 3000 concurrent users available, we look at server and db usage stats and use micro sites on Amazon's AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and increase the amount of power intensive tasks to guesstimate the impact of 3000 users to ie 300k (make the app work 1000 times slower with limited functionality and hardware etc), I recommend the same, you don't need 1000s of real users hitting your server

Answer (score 0):

You can enable trace in xDebug that will give you memory usage traces.
You can you free services like loadimpact to do a load test on your server (or use internal testers like ab, but less reliable in real world).
Here's how to enable trace:
    xdebug.auto_trace=1